# not getting a response from httpRequest when trying to post to timeline google glass

Tags: php, google-glass, google-mirror-api

`require('../config.php');
require('../HttpPost.class.php');
if(isset($_GET['code'])) {

```
$code = $_GET['code'];
$url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';

$params = array(
    "code" => $code,
    "client_id" => $oauth2_client_id,
    "client_secret" => $oauth2_secret,
    "redirect_uri" => $oauth2_redirect,
    "grant_type" => "authorization_code"
);

$request = new HttpPost($url);
$request->setPostData($params);
$request->send();

$responseObj = json_decode($request->getHttpResponse(), true); 
$access_token = $responseObj['access_token'];`
```

I followed the following code when trying to post content to the timeline of glass. https://github.com/backupbrain/google-mirror-insert-timeline-php
But i am getting an error on line 55 of `outh2callback/index.php` saying that `" Trying to get property of non-object"` which essentially means that there is no value in the `$request->getHttpResponse()`

Can anyone help me out on it as i am very new to glassware and i am trying to get hold of how things work!

Thank you !!

Comment: Can you post your code ? Interesting that you are trying something new.

Comment: $request = new HttpPost($url);
    $request->setPostData($params);
    $request->send();

        // decode the incoming string as JSON, this is line 55
    $responseObj = json_decode($request->getHttpResponse());

        // Tada: we have an access token!
        $access_token = $responseObj->access_token;

Comment: You can access the full code at the github link i mentioned.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't convert JSON response to PHP object? Use it as associative array. Try this: $responseObj = json_decode($request->getHttpResponse(), true); $access_token = $responseObj['access_token'];

Comment: I am not getting the error now, but still no value from getHttpResponse() !!

Comment: Can you please add a bit more code by editing your question? It comes through a lot more clear than in comments :)  Also, can you share the raw http response you see? (before you parse it)

Comment: I have edited the question to include the code ! config.php has the settings - client is and all ! HttpPost.class.php has the curl

Comment: IIRC, I've had problems with Google services before when I wasn't setting the useragent. Something to do with that perhaps?